# m2e eclipse maven plugin depedency management

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, dependencies, dependency-management, m2e

I have the m2e maven plugin installed on Eclipse (Kepler 64bit).
I have created a new project using a archtype. I then open up POM file using the 'Maven POM Editor'. I then go to the dependencies tab. Here i see 2 panes. One of the left says 'Dependencies'. I use this to add new dependencies to my project (like logback, junit, etc).

The right pane says 'Dependency Management'. What is this pane for? What are its uses?
Screenshot - [image: maven dependency management]

Comment: I have exactly the same confusion! Thanks for asking it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer here - http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management

"The dependency management section is a mechanism for centralizing dependency information. When you have a set of projects that inherits a common parent it's possible to put all information about the dependency in the common POM and have simpler references to the artifacts in the child POMs."

Comment: Add some details: We can *declare in detail* the dependencies in the parent pom. And then just *simply reference* them in each child pom as appropriate.